# Find the smallest positive integer $m$ and $n$ for which $13<2^\frac{m}{n}<14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Q: Find the smallest positive integers $m$ and $n$ for which $13<2^\frac{m}{n}<14$

No idea where to start

Question from year 11 Cambridge book

Comment: $13^n<2^m<14^n$ just try small $n= 1,2,3,4$ until there is a power of $2$ between the two

Comment: "Smallest $m$ and $n$" doesn't make sense. There are many different ways you can compare pairs of numbers.

Comment: Is there any law against calculators?  You know a= log_2 13 = ln 13/ln 2 < m/n < log_2 14 = ln 14/ln 2 = b.  So an < m < bn.  Just choose the smallest n so that there is an integer m so that is true.

Comment: Or will jagy's hint.

Answer (score 2):

There is guaranteed to be a fairly small answer because $\frac{14}{13} > 1$ and there is some bound $K$ such that 
$$ k \geq K \Longrightarrow \left( \frac{14}{13}  \right)^k > 2.  $$

Indeed
$$ \left( \frac{14}{13}  \right)^9 \approx 1.948,  $$
$$ \left( \frac{14}{13}  \right)^{10} \approx 2.098,  $$
so we were guaranteed to be able to take
$$  n \leq 10. $$
Going back to integers,
$$ 13^{10} = 137858491849 $$
$$ 2 \cdot 13^{10} = 275716983698  $$
$$ 14^{10} = 289254654976, $$
and this confirms that $14^{10} > 2 \cdot 13^{10}.$
There is definitely at least one power of two in between $13^{10}$ and $14^{10}.$ We expect that some exponent smaller that $10$ would work, although we have not proved a guarantee for that; just need to check, see what happens.

As your book evidently shows you, as soon as you get to
$$ 13^4 = 28561  \; \;  \mbox{and}  \; \; 14^4 = 38416  $$
there is a power of $2$ in between, namely
$$ 32768 = 2^{15} $$

Answer (score 2):

Taking logs throughout you get ...
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\log(13)}{\log (2)} &< \frac mn &<\frac{\log(14)}{\log (2)} 
\\ 3.700 &< \frac mn &<3.808
\end{eqnarray*}$$

From there I would put my money on the lowest fraction being at $3.75 = \frac{15}{4}$

Answer (score 0):

For every n, there is a smallest m such that $2^{m/n}>13$. Try n = 1, 2, 3, ..., finding the smallest such m for every n, until you find one where $2^{m/n}<14$.

It turns out that $2^{{15}/4}$ ≈ 13.4543; the solution is m = 15, n = 4.